# Even i click Stay on Page, event fire window.beforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {

    return "Content will be deleted";
    Cookies.remove('title');
    Cookies.remove('description');
    Cookies.remove('imageCollection');
    Cookies.remove('imageIdCollection');

     $.ajax({
       url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>myController/myFunction",
       type:'POST',
             }).done(function (data){
                 $("#display").html(data);
                 $('#loadingmessage').hide();

             });

         });
```

When i navigate to another page it show alert "Leave Page" or "Stay On Page" and ajax function fire whether i click stay on page.

How can i stop further function if user click "Stay On Page".

I want to call this method if user click Leave Page:

```
    Cookies.remove('title');
    Cookies.remove('description');
    Cookies.remove('imageCollection');
    Cookies.remove('imageIdCollection');

     $.ajax({
       url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>myController/myFunction",
       type:'POST',
             }).done(function (data){
                 $("#display").html(data);
                 $('#loadingmessage').hide();

             });
```

Is there is any event to handle "Stay On Page" and "Leave Page" button.

Answer (score 0):

your code is an unreachable and will throw error on console.

```
 Cookies.remove('title');
Cookies.remove('description');
Cookies.remove('imageCollection');
Cookies.remove('imageIdCollection');

 $.ajax({
   url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>myController/myFunction",
   type:'POST',
         }).done(function (data){
             $("#display").html(data);
             $('#loadingmessage').hide();

         });

     });
```

you should move this code to be bound to "unload" event instead of beforeunload.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {

return "Content will be deleted";
});

$(window).bind('unload', function() {
       Cookies.remove('title');
       Cookies.remove('description');
       Cookies.remove('imageCollection');
       Cookies.remove('imageIdCollection');

 $.ajax({
   url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>myController/myFunction",
   type:'POST',
         }).done(function (data){
             $("#display").html(data);
             $('#loadingmessage').hide();

         });


});
```

This should work for you.

Comment: I have another method like image uploading, which refresh page after image uploading. In above method it will remove all my data if i upload image. Because it will fire when page unload or refresh

Comment: you can set a global flag like isRefreshFromImageUpload=true in your image upload function to indicate the page is now getting refreshed due to image upload and not any other reason. Then you can read that flag in your unload event handler to not remove image related cookies.

Comment: Hope this has helped @Nabeel

Answer (score 0):

You can reference follow code:

```
var timeout;

function leavePage() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        Cookies.remove('title');
        Cookies.remove('description');
        Cookies.remove('imageCollection');
        Cookies.remove('imageIdCollection');

        $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>myController/myFunction",
          type:'POST',
        }).done(function (data){
          $("#display").html(data);
          $('#loadingmessage').hide();
        });
    }, 1000);
    return "You are leaving the page";
}

function clear() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}

window.onbeforeunload = leavePage;
window.unload = clear;​
```